# How to change progress bar color depending on the value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a progress bar using angular and bootstrap.It works fine for now, it shows progress value correctly. Now I want my progress bar use `types=" "` depending on the value of my property called progress. I tried implementing code from *UI Bootstrap* and some other stack overflow examples but I am missing something.

Can anyone help? Thanks for your time.

script.js

```
table.controller('workingPlan', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        "todos":[
            { "text":"starting work",  "progress":10},
            { "text":"middle of work","progress":50},
            { "text":"lunch brake", "progress":70},
            { "text":"finished working", "progress":100}
        ]   
    });

      $scope.changeType = function(todo) {
        var type;
        if (todo.progress < 30) {
          type = 'success';
        } else if (todo.progress < 60) {
          type = 'info';
        } else if (todo.progress < 90) {
          type = 'warning';
        } else {
          type = 'danger';
        }

        $scope.type = type;
      };
```

index.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="todo in plan>     
    <td><progressbar animate="false" value="todo.progress" type="{{todo.type}}"><b>{{todo.progress}}% </b></progressbar></t
</tr>
```

Comment: Please notice that, you declare changeType function, but you don't run it anywhere :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ng-class 
//Edit missing " after "todo in plan >

```
  <tr ng-repeat="todo in plan">     
     <td><progressbar animate="false" value="todo.progress" type="{{todo.type}}" 
     ng-class="{ 'progress-bar-success' : todo.type == 'succes' , 'progress-bar-info': todo.type == 'info', 'progress-bar-warning' : todo.type == 'warning' , 'progress-bar-danger': todo.type == 'danger'}"   >  
     <b>{{todo.progress}}% </b></progressbar></t
 </tr>
```

Comment: I believe this should work, but I am getting all progress bars blue. I will put my project in plunker in a minute.

Comment: create a plunkr, maybe there is a typo

Comment: I created a plunker AlainIb.

Comment: You put toooo much code in the plunkr, hard to understand. the type is always null

Comment: you should have one type per todo not only one in all the scope

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use the `Progress` value to determine the hue

```
ng-style="{'color':'hsl('+1.2*todo.progress+',100%,50%)'}"
```

this code will use 0%-100% to display the colors `hsl(0,100%,50%)` (red) to `hsl(120,100%,50%)` (green). Going over 100% will cause it to turn blue.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AvY9yurswHKPQY2qleZF?p=preview)